# Update array value in source php

Tags: php

It is common in php to store config data in arrays, and that is read only. Has someone made utility to make possible to save changes to array direct in source? I don't mean serializing array to some file but update value in source where it was read.

Comment: you wouldn't update xml directly either. you'd load the xml, parse it with a DOM engine, update whatever nodes you want, then export back to a new xml string. direct manipulation of config files is a bad idea - if your code crashes for any reason part-way through modifying the config file, you'll likely corrupt the file. it's best to write to a NEW file, then replace the original with the new one after saving is completed.

Comment: Not sure if I see a difference between either method - or why you'd think one was readonly and the other wasn't. In either case you have to read the data in - then have the option to save it back to source

Comment: That was just a remark about writable config, I'll delete that sentence to prevent misleading.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I manipulate and save the state of config arrays.

Here I create a config array (but let's assume you already have one in the same format), I write it.  Then next I read it in, make an edit and save back to the file.

Adjust to your liking.

```
<?php
function write_config($config, $path) {
    file_put_contents($path, '<?php return ' . var_export($config, true). ';');
}
function read_config($path)
{
    return include $path;
}

$config_path = '/tmp/config.php';
$config = array(
    'foo' => 'bar'
);

write_config($config, $config_path);
$config = read_config($config_path);
var_dump($config);
$config['foo'] = 'baz';
write_config($config, $config_path);
$config = read_config($config_path);
var_dump($config);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)
array (size=1)
  'foo' => string 'baz' (length=3)
```

I usually have a base array set with defaults, and have another array for adjustments that I use to override the first. I use array_merge_recursive to apply the latter over the first.